# PHP curl resume download

Tags: php, google-chrome, curl, satellite-image

I'm currently trying to download satellite images from esa's Copernicus / Sentinel project with curl. Unfortunately the download keeps stopping at around 90% and the php script returns an Internal Server Error (500).
Therefore I would like to resume the download at a specific byte number. It seems that the esa server just ignores the http-range-header (CURLOPT_RANGE) and CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM doesn't change anything either.
If I use Google Chrome to download the file manually, the download also interrupts but continues after some time.
**So, if Google Chrome can resume the download, curl should be able to do that, too. I would appreciate any help on how to do that.**
Some details:
The file I'm trying to download is [here](https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('1726bb80-d1f0-418a-a130-173fc0429a89')/Nodes('S1A_IW_GRDH_1SDV_20150916T054218_20150916T054231_007736_00ABFB_58CF.SAFE')/Nodes('measurement')/Nodes('s1a-iw-grd-vh-20150916t054218-20150916t054231-007736-00abfb-002.tiff')/$value) (420MB), to access it you need to register at scihub.esa.int/dhus/.
Content-Type is `application/octet-stream`
My code:

```
$save_file = fopen($save_filepath, "w+");
$open_file = curl_init(str_replace(" ","%20", $url));
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_FILE, $save_file);
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, "trackprogress");
curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_exec($open_file);
curl_close($open_file);
fclose($save_file);
```

It works perfectly for smaller files (I've tested it with some images and pdf-files) and I can also download most of the satellite image (the first 380MB are downloaded). I tried to increase the timeout value, too, but the script terminates long before the 5 minutes are reached.
I tried `curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, 1048576);` and `curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_RANGE, "1048576-");` but the file always starts with the same bytes.
**EDIT:**
I can't answer my question, but for this specific case I found a workaround. So, if anybody reads this and also wants to download these satellite images with cURL by chance, here is what I did:
When downloading not just the image file, but the zip-file with some additional data, the download still keeps stopping, however with `curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, $bytes_already_loaded);` it is possible to skip the bytes which had previously been loaded and resume the download (which isn't possible for the image file). Thus, use this [link](https://scihub.esa.int/dhus/odata/v1/Products('1726bb80-d1f0-418a-a130-173fc0429a89')/$value) instead of the image file.

Comment: sounds like a file size limit and exe time limit on your server. change your php server settings.

Comment: The file size limit is no problem, actually the first time I tried to run the script I was lucky: the download wasn't interrupted and the whole file was downloaded. But this was the only time it worked. And I just wrote and tested a php script which would have run infinitely if I hadn't interrupted it after 10 minutes.

Comment: Or there's a limit on the other end of the server per single IP. They don't want people to take up their bandwidth.

Comment: I tried to use `curl_setopt($open_file, CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE, 2000000);` to limit the transfer speed and the download was slower but stopped at 93%, anyhow.